# does quickfixj's disconnect method sends logout message to other party

Tags: java, quickfixj

I have noticed that there is no logout message present in the session logs when my application disconnects from the session using :

```
session.disconnect(reason, false);
```

I have verified that the method does get called and even found the reason in the qfixj framework logs but saw no logout message going to the other connected compid. i do not understand whether this is the intended behavior or is it due to some other issue. im using quickfixj 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickfixj does not send logout message when we explicitly disconnect from the session.